# Unable to initialize the automatic property in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5

I have an automatic property

public int GearCount { get; set; }

when i try to initialize it like this-

Tandem t = new Tandem(GearCount = 5);

It gives an error as below

The name 'GearCount' does not exist in the current context

Whats wrong here ?
Also if i do normal intantiation it works fine.
Tandem t = new Tandem();

Comment: Did you mean Tandem t = new Tandem() { GearCount = 5 }; ?

Comment: What is the relation between `GearCount` and `HasToolkit`?

Comment: sorry for typo. i have replaced hastoolkit with Gearcount.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

<strike>**We need the rest of your code**</strike>

You show us an auto-property called `HasToolkit` but the problem you're having has nothing to do with `HasToolkit`.

It doesn't look like you have an auto-property on your `Tandem` class called `GearCount`.

With the question fixed, it looks like you might just have some syntax issues.

If your `Tandem` class looks like:

```
public class Tandem
{    
   public bool HasToolkit {get; set;}

   public int GearCount {get; set;}
}
```

Then your initialization code would be:

```
Tandem t = new Tandem() { GearCount = 5 };
```

Or:

```
Tandem t = new Tandem() { GearCount = 5, HasToolkit = true };
```

Comment: No problem. Updated now that you changed the question around.

Answer (score 2):

The property you have declared is not the same name nor type as the one you are trying to set in the initializer. In addition, you need to use braces instead of parentheses when you want to use initializers:

```
var t = new Tandem{ HasToolKit = true };
```

Comment: thanks !! my mistake, it was a typo.. have fixed the question now.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the property is named `HasToolKit` and is of type `bool`, not named `GearCount` with a type of `int`.

To that end, you also seem to be mixing constructor and property initializer syntax.  What you'd want in the calling case is:

```
Tandem t = new Tandem {GearCount = 5};
```

The definition of Tandem would need to have something of the sort of:

```
public int GearCount { get; set; }
```

Not quite sure what `HasToolKit` means in the scheme of things.

Comment: thank u so much !!!!  I highly appriciate ur help . like u said i was actually mixing up the constructor syntax and property initialization syntax

Comment: Glad to be of help.  Happy coding!